# Error while compiling assets in Prestashop

Tags: php, bash, makefile, prestashop

I decided to study Prestashop and during the preparation of the development environment during the compilation of assets through the console and the make assets command, an error appears as in the screenshot.

I have installed: XAMMP 8.0, Prestashop 8.0, GnuWin 32 and chocolatey. I tried many options both on this forum and on other sites - the error remained. Does anyone have any ideas or solutions to this problem?

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\presta> make assets
./tools/assets/build.sh
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, bash C:\xampp\htdocs\presta\tools\assets\build.sh, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [Makefile:7: assets] Error 2
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\presta>
```

Comment: Please don't post images.  Instead edit your question, cut and paste the text into your question, and format it as a code block.  Also to get the best possible help it's best to run in the default C locale which will display error messages in English (at least if you cut and paste the text then people can run it through a translator).

Comment: It looks like there's no program `bash` installed on your system, while this makefile apparently expects one to be there.  I suspect that this makefile contains a line like `SHELL := bash` to force all recipes to run using the bash shell.  Likely this build environment was written for GNU/Linux (or possibly MacOS) and hasn't been ported to run on Windows.

Comment: @MadScientist Yes you are right. There is a line at the beginning of the file `#!/bin/bash`. I thought that just the GnuWin32 program was supposed to solve this problem, but no. I consulted with a friend and he says that he only installed some packages and everything worked.

Comment: Still cant solve it

Comment: Did you install `bash`?  Can you run `bash` from your command line, without getting an error?

Comment: @MadScientist
No, i have error
`PS D:\tools\xamp\htdocs\prestashop> bash
bash : The term 'bash' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ bash
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (bash:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS D:\tools\xamp\htdocs\prestashop>`

Comment: Well, you'll have to fix that.  How can make invoke `bash` for you, when you can't invoke it yourself?  If your question is really, "how can I install `bash` on my Windows computer" then please rejigger the question and title, and set the tags on your question appropriately to draw the attention of people who might be able to answer.  Your question really has nothing to do with make, or "prestashop", or php, and you need to specially ask for windows else people who follow the "bash" tag (who are mostly not people who use Windows) won't be able to answer it.